# Minesweeper (not algorithm but just layout questions)

Tags: java, android, minesweeper

I'm trying to make layout of minesweeper in Android studio. But it doesn't show up anything on emulator. it just show "Application Name" Keeps stopping. (is it emulator problem? or code problem?). there is no any red underbar or error sign when i build this code.
here's my code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class MainActivity extends 
AppCompatActivity
{

    TableLayout table;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            table.addView(tableRow);
        }

        Button[][] buttons = new Button[9][9];

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j] = new Button(this);
            }
        }

        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<9; j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                tableRow.addView(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

I have to make minesweeper in this way.
1. Make 9by9 minesweeper with addView() method of TableLayout.
2. Make 9 TableRow.
3. 81 Buttons and 9 TableRow have to be dynamically allocated. (only TableLayout can be allocated in xml file)
4. And I have to use this sample codes

1)

```
TableLayout table; table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
table.addView(tableRow);
```

2)

```
Button[][] buttons = new Button[9][9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
    {
        buttons[i][j] = new Button(this);
    } 
}
```

3)

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams =  new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f); 
button[i][j].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
tableRow.addView(buttons[i][j]);
```

Comment: And your question is? There is no question in your post. Just an exercise to solve.

Comment: ok. "it doesn't work" can you be more specific on that part? "with no any error" sure about that? either it works, or there is an error, if only wrong behaviour. "some basic question" why don't you ask them then?

Comment: sorry for my bad English I didn't mean for use a word "Basic" that way....

Comment: If it shows: "app name has stopped" is that there is an error. And that you need to check the logcat to see it.

Comment: I found my problem. my computer's lancard driver is dead. Think i have to format my computer. thank you for your advice!

Comment: Sorry to ask, but... Your android app crashes because your lan card is dead? Your app doesn't even have any connection or does it?